# Unable to install R 4.1.3 in fastapi Docker image

Tags: python, r, docker

I'm using a dockerfile which uses tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8-slim-2021-06-09 as base image and installs the required linux package and also installs r-recommended and r-base. Earlier below dockerfile works fine. But when I tried to update the image with tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8-slim-2023-01-09 as base image, unable to install the r-recommended and r-base with version 4.1.2-1~bustercran.0.

**Dockerfile :**

```
# Download IspR from IspR project pipeline and extract the folder and rename it as r-scripts. Place the r-scripts directory in backend root directory.
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8-slim-2023-01-09

COPY key_gnupg.gpg /app/key_gnupg.gpg
COPY packages.txt /app/packages.txt
RUN echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until \"false\";\nAcquire::Check-Date \"false\";" | cat > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10no--check-valid-until
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2=2.2.27-2+deb11u2 && \
     echo "deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cran.list && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B8F25A8A73EACF41 && \
    apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y $(cat /app/packages.txt) && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get purge --auto-remove && \
   apt-get clean
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/r-scripts
RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes')"
RUN renv_version=`cat renv.lock | grep -A3 "renv" | grep -e "Version" | cut -d ':' -f2 | sed "s/\"//g" | sed "s/\,//g"|awk '{$1=$1};1'` && \
    R -e "remotes::install_github('rstudio/renv@${renv_version}')" && \
    rm -rf /app
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

**packages.txt**

```
git=1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3
pkg-config=0.29-6
liblapack-dev=3.8.0-2
gfortran=4:8.3.0-1
libxml2=2.9.4+dfsg1-7+deb10u3
libxml2-dev=2.9.4+dfsg1-7+deb10u3
libssl-dev=1.1.1n-0+deb10u1
libcurl4-openssl-dev=7.64.0-4+deb10u2
libnlopt-dev=2.4.2+dfsg-8+b1
libpcre2-8-0=10.32-5
build-essential=12.6
r-recommended=4.1.2-1~bustercran.0
r-base=4.1.2-1~bustercran.0
curl=7.64.0-4+deb10u2
postgresql=11+200+deb10u4
libpq-dev=11.14-0+deb10u1
libblas-dev=3.8.0-2
libgomp1=8.3.0-6
zlib1g-dev=1:1.2.11.dfsg-1
zlib1g=1:1.2.11.dfsg-1
```

*Error MEssage :*

```
E: Version '4.1.2-1~bustercran.0' for 'r-base-core' was not found
```

How to install the 4.1.2 version of r-base using this Dockerfile?

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to help you without at least an error message.

Comment: Updated with Error message

Comment: Looks like the specific version of r-base specified in your packages.txt isn't available on whatever version of linux fastapi has upgraded to. You should probably fire up a container based on the latest fastapi image and use `apt-cache search` to find out the right version.